# Como fazer uma query passando um array por parâmetro no firestore?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, nosql, firestore

Eu tenho uma lista de documentos no firestore, chamada compras. Dentro de cada compra dessas, eu tenho um CAMPO, chamado condicaoPagamento, esse guarda a condição de pagamento da compra. O que eu preciso agora é, fornecer ao usuário, a possibilidade de recuperar todos os documentos que contenham uma determinada condição de pagamento. Até ai tudo bem, o problema vem a seguir.

Esse filtro, ele da a possibilidade ao usuário, de escolher mais de uma condição de pagamento para consultar, vamos supor por ex: a pessoa pode escolher, cheque, dinheiro e cartão.

Então eu tenho que pegar essa matriz de opções que ela escolheu, e fazer uma query nessa lista de compras do firestore, aonde eu preciso comparar a matriz que foi fornecida pelo usuário, com os campos que existem lá dentro.

Eu vi na documentação, que é possível comparar um campo com uma matriz do firestore, porém o que eu preciso é o inverso, eu preciso comparar uma matriz com os campos do firestore, alguém já fez isso alguma vez ?

Segue o meu treco de código de como estou tentando fazer isso, porém sem sucesso até o momento.

```
carregarComprasFiltrosCondicoesPagamento() {
this.compras = [];
this.db.collection("usuarios_adm_proprietarios")
.where("uidUsuario", "==", this.uidUsuario)
  .get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      this.idEmpresa = doc.data().idEmpresa;
      let ref = this.db.collection("empresas")
        .doc(this.idEmpresa)
        .collection("compras")
        .where("status", "==", "concluida")
        .where("condicaoPagamento", "array-contains", this.condicoesPagamento)
        .orderBy("dataEmissaoISOString", "desc")
        .limit(this.limite);
      ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        this.ultimaCompraCarregada = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          this.compras = querySnapshot.docs.map(d => d.data());
          this.calcularTotalCompras();
        });
      })
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
  });
}
```

Eu recebo a matriz de opções de filtro dos meus usuários dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meus documentos no firestore, gravam a condição de pagamento dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

```
let filtro = [] // Filtro com os parâmetros selecinados

filtro.map((element) => {
    firebase.firestore().collection("pedidos").where("condicaoPagamento", "==", element)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {

            let retornofiltro = [] // array final com os dados filtrados do firestore 
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                retornofiltro.push(doc.data())
            })
            conso.log()
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
        })

        conso.log(retornofiltro)

})
```